# Individual estimates accuracy report on Jira

Tags: jira, estimation

I would like to know how accurate I am estimating user stories.

I log my time in Jira + Greenhopper and I had a look to time [tracking reports](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Time+Tracking+Report)  but I'm not sure of how to filter stories by individual user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get all the stats I needed by creating a simple application which connects to the Jira REST API using their [Jira REST Client](https://studio.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JRJC/Home).

Writing a Jira plugging could be also a solution but I think is far more complicated.